# Does dropping a table's unique key pose any problems in production?

Tags: mysql

I'll expound a bit on my question, if I have a live database in production and I want to drop a Unique Key from one of the tables, be it a non-composite unique key or a composite one, will that pose any problems?

I'm thinking this shouldn't pose any problems but I want to double check with the DB experts here.

As for the composite unique key question, I want to drop it because I want to add a new column to that composite unique key.

So this:

```
UNIQUE KEY `composite_key` (`username`, `email`),
```

Becomes this:

```
UNIQUE KEY `composite_key` (`username`, `email`, `age`),
```

Is there a way to "add" a column to the composite unique key? Or do I have drop it first and then define/add a new unique key composing of those 3 new columns? And again, will there be a problem if I do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be performance problems during the period between removing the old key and adding the new key, if queries are performed that depend on the key. But otherwise I think it should be safe. If the key is required for a foreign key, I suspect (or at least hope) it won't allow you to remove it.

Instead of removing the old key and then adding a new one, you could add the new one first (you'll have to give it a different name) and then remove the old one. The only downside to this is the increased storage during the overlap period.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess the unique key name is not really important  for anything? It's just used for naming purposes?

Comment: AFAIK, the only place the name is used is if you want to force use of a specific index in a query.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601138/what-is-the-significance-of-the-index-name-when-creating-an-index-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks for the link. What do you mean by "force use a specific index in a query"? Are you saying I can do this "SELECT composite_index_name FROM table"? If yes, will that return me data on all columns of the composite index?